# Update a Label to show 10000 to 0 in 10 Seconds using NSTimer

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, nstimer

There is one label which display Score from 10,000 to 0 in 10 seconds (lblPoints)

```
    NSTimer pointstimer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(pointstimermethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];

    -(void)pointstimermethod
    {
        points=points-1;
        lblPoints.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",points];
    }
```

Can anyone show me how I can display 10,000 to 0 in exactly and precisely 10 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display only updates at 60 Hz max, and NSTimer firing accuracy depends on what's going on in the UI run loop, and thus may have errors of one to several display frame times (over 10 mS), certainly not 1 mS resolution.  Lots of numbers between 10000 and 0 will be skipped since the device can only display 600 unique frames max in 10 seconds.

I would try using CADisplayLink set for a 60 Hz display update (that's the max), check the current time using mach_time, subtract that from some start time, subtract that from 10.0 to get a count down, and display 1000X the difference in seconds until 0.0 seconds is reached.

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad method paste bellow code

```
NSTimer pointstimer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(pointstimermethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];

    -(void)pointstimermethod
    {
        points=points-1;
        if(points >= 0 && points <= 10000){
              lblPoints.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",points];
        }
    }
```

i hope this help you mate..

:)

Comment: I guess this wont work! As you're suggestion 10.0 as interval. As it'll only reduce -1 at every 10 seconds. Its oppose to question. You should update your answer.

Comment: this will call method pointstimermethod every 10 seconds,i want to call this method faslty that it can show 10000 to 0 in 10 seconds

Comment: hey dude here in scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 you define the second as 10.0 if you want to fast then descrese it with 1.0 like scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0

Answer (score 1):

Declare the following .h file.

```
int points;
```

In the implementation file, have the following code.

```
-(void)showScore:(id)sender {
    points = 10000;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(pointsTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)pointsTimerMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    points=points-1;
    lblPoints.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",points];

    if(points == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Just call the `showScore:` method when you want to show that from 10000 to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but,this is what i was already doing,if you can see in my question,and i was assigning points to 10000 also

Comment: Yes, but you are not invalidating the timer once it reaches Zero. Otherwise, what is your problem?

Comment: i can't invalidate timer ,as i have to reuse it,in fact i want to show this 10000 to 0 display every 10 seconds and i have to do this for 60 to 0 seconds

Comment: thanks for your answer but i tried exactly what you said but not working as intended

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimer pointstimer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(pointstimermethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];

-(void)pointstimermethod
{
    if(pointstimer==0)
    {
       [pointstimer invalidate]; 
    }
    else
    {
        points=points-1;
        lblPoints.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",points];
    }
}
```